# why does XML sitemap on a sharepoint online website gets downloaded?

Tags: sharepoint, seo, office365

The XML sitemap of the website in sharepoint online (office 365) always get downloaded.Can anyone tell me what could be the reason behind it and most important how to resolve it? Please help

Thanks,

Avy

Comment: Can you please tell how did you access the sitemap.xml file in sharepoint online?

Comment: Its there inside the content folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint Online only opens a few file types in the browser.
xml isn't one of them.it’s a normal behavior that the file is downloaded